# How to integrate a pwa as a section into an existing android and ios app?

Tags: android, ios, progressive-web-apps

We have some PWA's for flight, hotel booking, etc. we want to add it as a separate section and open it in our existing Android and IOS apps(Native apps).

we are trying to achieve the same behaviour as in native app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use a webview in your native apps. It is possible for IOS and Android but you will never have the same "feeling" as a native app. For further information check the documentation of Google and Apple:

[Android Web View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView)

[iOS WebKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview)

Comment: For Android [Trusted Web Activites](https://blog.chromium.org/2019/02/introducing-trusted-web-activity-for.html) would be better than just a plain web view.